# Displaying version and date of build in the xhtml page from manifest in run time

Tags: maven, glassfish, manifest, war

```
            Enumeration<URL> resources = getClass().getClassLoader()
                            .getResources("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
```

//Can't find resource name META-INF/MANIFEST.MF ?

Comment: Please add more content in question to describe the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct resource name is /applications/ProjectName/META INF/MANIFEST.MF
.
Replace ProjectName with your project name.
Updated the code according below:
.
.
Enumeration resources = getClass().getClassLoader()
.getResources("/applications/ProjectName/META INF/MANIFEST.MF");
.
.